# Starting repo from fork of existing repo

Tags: git, flask, github-pages

I've been learning Flask using Miguel Grinberg's superb book and accompanying Flasky app which I've cloned to a local repo.

Up to and including tag 10d Flasky is 95% what I need as a starting point for my own app.  After that it diverges a lot.

What I therefore want to do is "clone" (if that's the right word) Flasky as at tag 10d, losing everything after that tag and also losing the history before that tag, so I end up with a clean repo that has just the 10d version in it. I can then build on that for my own app.

I'm unsure what Git commands I need to do this.

Comment: you need to clone, checkout the correct tag. Then create a new git repository and copy all the files (but .git) to it. Doing so, you will not be able to easily merge against the latest changes in the original repo. Maybe the better idea would be to keep all the history and just create your own branch at the tag.

Answer (score 1):

You can run `git clone --depth 1 --branch 10d https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/flasky.git`.

Explanation of parameters (more details [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone)):

- `--branch 10d` will get the repository state at the tag you specified
- `--depth 1` will truncate the history to keep only 1 commit

After the `clone` operation is done, it will however still be a Git repository. You must delete the `.git` folder in order for it to become a regular folder: `rm -rf ./flasky/.git`.

You will then have the source files you want! You can then create your own repository by running `git init`.